# How to know if CHKDSK is still running?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I am trying to repair one of my disks with CHKDSK. Unfortunately, I get the following message:

"corruption was found while examining the volume bitmap"

Now, I don't know if it is still running or if it has stopped. The HDD indicator light is blinking, indicating some kind of access. Yet, I don't know if the access is caused by CHKDSK or some other thing. Closing the command line, and trying to access the HDD proves futile, as access is denied once cmd is closed.

I want to know if there is any way to know if the command is still running and if it will ever end.

Other Info:

SMART tests were passed by the drive.
System is exFat
Manufacturer is Western Digital
External HDD
OS is Windows 7

Comment: Bitmap corruption is usually a free space issue which can be fixed using chkdsk /r command which will schedule chksk to run on the next boot to repair this issue. Free space issues cause serious disk performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there is any way to know if the command is still running

Open the Task Manager, click the "Processes" tab, click "Show processes for all users", and look for a `CHKDSK.exe` process.

If you see one, then it's still running.

> if it will ever end

Generally yes it will end eventually. But if the drive is in rough shape, and/or has damage, and depending on drive size, and which arguments you ran CHKDSK with, then it could take MANY HOURS for it to finish.

If you want to try and see what's accessing the disk, use Windows' in-built Resource Monitor.

Comment: perhaps he only run on cmd, on my case i only have access to cmd. And it process already running for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Once you closed the command prompt, the `chkdsk` program was closed with it.

Comment: This is technically correct; if you've closed the command prompt, chkdsk is no longer running.  However, it might be valuable to include a warning in case it's misinterpretted as a "how to".  Readers might think that this is a simple solution for stopping chkdsk if it seems to be taking too long.  They should be advised that interrupting chkdsk can cause corruption and they shouldn't do it, at least not without verifying that it is no longer functioning.